# php create several objects within object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am trying to make a soap request and it needs to have this structure

```
$requestBody=new sendDataExtraccionRequest(new sendDataExtraccionSubterranea("18-09-2020","00:02:01",1234567891,12345678.12,12345678.12),
                                           new sendDataExtraccionSubterranea("18-09-2020","00:03:01",1234567891,12345678.12,12345678.12));
```

thought that by creating an array with each object and then cast it should do, but getting an error on the soap call that the date field is missing

```
$array_datos[] = new sendDataExtraccionSubterranea("03-02-2021","00:02:01",1234567891,12345678.12,12345678.12);
$array_datos[] = new sendDataExtraccionSubterranea("03-02-2021","00:03:01",1234567891,12345678.12,12345678.12);

$requestBody=new sendDataExtraccionRequest( (object)$array_datos );
```

Also tried a solution that involved json encoding and decoding the array, but same error

Any hint on how to achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spread Operator like this

```php
$requestBody=new sendDataExtraccionRequest(...$array_datos);
```

Comment: For information, "Argument unpacking" or "Splat operator" is available as of [PHP 5.6](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)

Comment: Great, this worked.
Didn't know this existed on php, read about it on javascript.
Thanks!